# Package to import to use SystemFactory with Joda Time

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I am using Joda time in Java. What package do I need to import to use the following statement?

```
DateTime now = SystemFactory.getClock().getDateTime();
```

I'm getting the error "SystemFactory cannot be resolved".

Is that part of the Joda library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.phpfirefly.test.joda.factory.SystemFactory
```

It is not a part of Joda library.
Instead use below line:

```
private static final DateTime theDateTime = new DateTime(2009, 9, 6, 14, 30, 0, 0);
```

NOTE:
If you are using an IDE, then it will assist you in importing appropriate packages.